# How to correctly perform Linq-to-XML query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a `XDocument` called `currentIndex` like that:

```
<INDEX>
   <SUBINDEX>
      <!-- Many tag and infos -->
   <SUBINDEX>
   <ITEM>
       <IDITEM>1</IDITEM>
   <ITEM>
   <ITEM>
       <IDITEM>2</IDITEM>
   <ITEM>
   ...
   <ITEM>
       <IDITEM>n</IDITEM>
   <ITEM>
</INDEX>
```

I would recreate a new `XDocument` similar to above one:

```
<INDEX>
   <SUBINDEX>
      <!-- Many tag and infos -->
   <SUBINDEX>
   <ITEM>
       <IDITEM>2</IDITEM>
   <ITEM>
</INDEX>
```

I want to do this in C#, I have tried starting in this way:

```
public void ParseItems(XDocument items)
{
    IEnumerable<XElement> items = from a in indexGenerale.Descendants(XName.Get("ITEM"))
                                  // where a.Element("IDITEM").Equals("2")
                                  select a;
    foreach(var item in items) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now the problem: If `where` clause is commented, `items` contains `n` elements (one for each `ITEM` tag), but if I remove that comments items is empty. Why this behaviour. How I need to perform a search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an explicit cast:

```
from a in indexGenerale.Descendants("ITEM")
where (string)a.Element("IDITEM") == "2"
```

`a.Element("IDITEM")` will return an `XElement` and it will never be equal to `"2"`.Maybe you meant `a.Element("IDITEM").Value.Equals("2")`, that will also work but explicit cast is safer.It doesn't throw exception if the element wasn't found`,